# How to solve for an Z-Score of a T-Distribution?

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I'm looking for the Z-Score for a distribution, where the integrated area sums up to 0.90. Unfortunately I always get an error from Mathematica, `"nonnumerical value"`. Does someone know why?

```
Solve[NIntegrate[PDF[StudentTDistribution[49], x], {x, -Infinity, y}] == 0.95, y]
```

I tried as well

```
Solve[StudentTPValue[x, 49] == 0.10, x]
```

How can one get only the value as an output?
I ultimately want to test a hypothesis value to check if they are in the `0.95±∞` part of a Student-t distribution.

Comment: Search for ?NumericQ for more information about why the first line does not work.

Comment: objective[y_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[PDF[StudentTDistribution[49], x], {x, -Infinity, y}]; InverseFunction[objective][0.95]

Comment: What is the problem with just using the built-in solution `InverseCDF[StudentTDistribution[49], 0.95]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindRoot.html)? It's a numerical function looking for a root given some starting location. In addition to that, you can get around integrating by using [`CDF`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CDF.html) instead of `PDF` in the first place:

```
FindRoot[CDF[StudentTDistribution[49], y] == 0.95, {y, 1}]
```

> ```
> {y -> 1.67655}
> ```

If you're interested, the reason why your first approach doesn't work: `NIntegrate` cannot use placeholders, it has to evaluate to a number in all cases. What you're trying to do is equivalent to `NIntegrate[x*y, {x,0,1}]`, and the program complains that it does not know the full integrand since y is undefined, therefore it cannot be evaluated. The fact that you've wrapped a `Solve`, which inserts the missing variable (`x` in your case) *after* `NIntegrate` has been evaluated, does not have any impact on that.

Comment: thank you for your help, both solutions work well, sometimes I feel like its very hard to compute with mathematica, the next time I think again its so convenient :P

Answer (score 13):

David's method is the route I would go if I didn't want to use `Quantile` for some reason.

```
Quantile[StudentTDistribution[49], .95]

==> 1.67655
```

If you really want to use PDF's to demonstrate this you can still use `FindRoot` by first setting the integration up so that it only accepts numeric input.

```
f[y_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[PDF[StudentTDistribution[49], x], {x, -Infinity, y}]

FindRoot[f[y] == 0.95, {y, 1}]

==> {y -> 1.67655}
```