# Solving Integrals

Tags: equation-solving

Here's a problem that I don't understand.

```
f[x_] := Exp[Cos[3*x]]
g[x_] := (1/3)*x^3 - x^2 + 2
```

When I try to find the limit:

```
Solve[NIntegrate[f[x] - 0.1 g[x], {x, 0, t}] == 3, t]
```

I get these errors x3

> NIntegrate::nlim:
>
> Solve::inex: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact
>   coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of
>   inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used
>   by Solve require exact input, providing Solve with an exact version of
>   the system may help. >>

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2428/

Answer (score 7):

```
h[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f[x] - 0.1 g[x], {x, 0, t}]

FindRoot[h[t] == 3, {t, 1}]
```

> {t -> 2.353038699}

Comment: Just note that if you include the `NIntegrate` expression directly within the `FindRoot` expression (instead of definning a function `h`), then you don't need the `?NumericQ` qualification.

Comment: @murray Have you actually tried that? It generates a whole bunch of messages before giving the same answer.

Comment: I had tried it and didn't get messages, but when I tried it again just now I get them. Not sure what in my environment earlier suppressed the messages!

Answer (score 4):

When solving integral equations numerically it's usually good to interpolate the integral since they tend to be slow to calculate, here I use `NDSolve`toget an approximation `hP[t]` $\approx \int_0^t h(x)dx$

```
f[x_]:=Exp[Cos[3*x]]
g[x_]:=(1/3)*x^3-x^2+2
h[x_]:=f[x]-0.1g[x]
Clear[hP]
hP=hP/.First@NDSolve[{hP[0]==0,hP'[t]==h[t]},hP,{t,0,10}];
```

And when solving equations you don't always have unique solutions so where you start your search affects which solution you'll find

```
plot = Plot[{hP[t], 3}, {t, 0, 10}];
Manipulate[
 (* Start looking for solution near supplied x *)
 root = t /. FindRoot[hP[t] == 3, {t, x, 0, 10}];
 (* Display the discovered root *)
 Column@{
   Row@{"Starting at Subscript[t, 0]=",x},
   Row@{"Root at t=", root},
   Show[{
     plot,
     Graphics[{
       {Blue, Point[{x, hP[x]}]},
       Disk[{root, hP[root]}, 0.1]
       }]
     }]}
 , {{x, 0, "First search position"}, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Output]

Update: It might seem predictable which root it will find but try starting at $t_0$ = 0.74 or 1.3 and you'll see that it finds the root at 5.7

Answer (score 1):

If what you really need is to know the $t$ value where equality occurs, you can do it interactively:

```
 Manipulate[NIntegrate[f[x] - 0.1` g[x], {x, 0, t}], {t, 0, 10}]
```

Just move the slider until the answer is 3. In this case, it's about t=2.3535.