# NIntegrate and FindRoot Results Correct?

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

I am trying to find the value of $k$ (maybe it does not exist) for

$$\displaystyle \int_k^2 \dfrac{1}{\ln{v}-v} ~ dv=1$$
I used [Solving Integrals](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16422/solving-integrals) for my approach as

```
f[k_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[1/(Log[x] - x), {x, k, 2}]

FindRoot[f[k] == 1, {k, 2}]
```

This returns

$${k = 3.7864655704597134}$$

This result is larger than the upper limit of the integration value.

I use Windows 7, MMA version $11.0.1.0$.

Is this approach wrong or am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: I get this result for `k` : `{k -> 3.78647}` with version 11.01 on Mach OS X.

Comment: I redid it with a fresh kernel and got your result, however, that result is larger than the higher limit of integration, so that confuses me.

Comment: Then you should put appropriate constraints to your problem formulation or change the integrand.

Comment: Please look at the stated integral - it was already there. In fact, why is FindRoot not observing the upper limit placed on $k$?

Comment: When we think about the graph of $\ln x$ vs $x$, we are reminded that $x > \ln x$ for all positive $x$.  Therefore the integrand is negative for all positive values of $x$.  To get a positive value for the integral, we must evaluate it from a greater value of $x$ to a lesser value of $x$.  The "lower" limit on an integral does not mean it is numerically less than the "upper" limit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not really a Mathematica issue but a matter of the OP not having grasped the mathematics involved.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that you have some previous definitions that are not cleared. Using your definitions in a fresh notebook:

```
f[k_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[1/(Log[x] - x), {x, k, 2}]
FindRoot[f[k] == 1, {k, 2}]
(*{k -> 3.78647}*)
```

Checking the solution:

```
f[3.7864655704597134`]
(*1.*)
NIntegrate[1/(Log[x] - x), {x, 3.7864655704597134`, 2}]
(*1.*)
```

Comment: I redid it with a fresh kernel and got your result, however, that result is larger than the higher limit of integration, so that confuses me.

Comment: @Moo - If you plot the integrand, i.e., `Plot[1/(Log[x] - x), {x, 1, 4}]` you will see that the integrand is negative in the range of interest. Consequently, to get a positive integral, the lower bound of the integration must be greater than the upper bound.

Comment: @BobHanlon: That makes sense - back to the drawing board - something is wrong in the result as this does not work. Rats! Thank you.

Comment: @Marchi: Why does FindRoot not observe the upper limit placed on $k$? That is, we have FindRoot[f[k] == 1, {k, 2}], so shouldn't $k$ be no greater than $2$?

Comment: @Moo:  No.  The `{k,2}` in your `FindRoot` tells *Mathematica* to *start* at $k=2$ and find the closest root (higher or lower).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: Thanks - I misread that!