# How to determine a limit of integration from a known integral?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have an integral equation for a value `t` between the limits of integration 1 and a parameter `u`. I am trying to solve for `u` with known values of `t` ranging from 0 to 14 in steps of 1

I am not sure how to go about this calculation, any help would be appreciated!

My code is:

```
eq = 1/(ξ (-1.66334 - 0.44 Log[ξ] + 1.66116 ξ))
t = NIntegrate[eq, {ξ, 1, u}]
```

Essentially this is being used for the following plot:

```
S = 762*u
p1 = 
  ParametricPlot[{t, S}, {u, 1, 0.02902}, 
    Frame -> True, 
    Axes -> False, 
    FrameLabel -> {"t (days)", "S(t)"}, 
    PlotRange -> All, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
    PlotStyle -> Red]
```

I am trying to find the exact values of `S` at various values of `t`. For example, I know that when `t = 0`, `S = 762`. I wish to extract data at values of `t` in the sequence 0, 1, ..., 14. Therefore, I thought by knowing values of `u`, I could work out `S`.

Is there an easier way to extract exact data values from a plot? I have tried using the get-coordinates` tool, but find this is not give the accuracy I require.

Plot produced is below:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16422/solving-integrals/16426#16426

Comment: You have a problem, a pole: `Plot[1/(\[Xi] (-1.66334 - 0.44 Log[\[Xi]] + 1.66116 \[Xi])), {\[Xi], 1, 1.02}, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: So `u < 1`, perhaps? There is still a pole at `\[Xi] -> 0.0250815`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alternatively, you can rephrase the problem as a differential equation and use `NDSolve`:

```
eq[x_] := 1/(x (-1.66334 - 0.44 Log[x] + 1.66116 x));
sol = First@NDSolve[{u'[t] == 1/eq[u[t]], u[0] == 1}, u, {t, 0, 14}];
uVals = Table[u[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 14}]
NIntegrate[eq[x], {x, 1, #}] & /@ uVals
```

> ```
> {1., 0.995745, 0.981588, 0.936796, 0.814854, 0.583019, 0.334263, 0.177939, 
>  0.102363, 0.0669098, 0.0492174, 0.0396957, 0.0342333,0.0309452, 0.0288969}
>
> {0., 1.00001, 2.00001, 3.00001, 4.00001, 5.00001, 6.00001, 7.00001, 
>  8.00001, 9.00001, 10., 11., 12., 13., 14.}
> ```

The integrand has poles at

```
Solve[1/eq[x] == 0, x]
```

> ```
> {{x -> 0.0250815}, {x -> 1.00178}}
> ```

as well as `x == 0`, but these are exactly avoided by the solutions in `uVals`.

Answer (score 3):

`NIntegrate` can't deal with an undecided limit. So you can't directly use `u` here.

I tried `Plot`, but it looks messy.

```
Plot[NIntegrate[eq, {ξ, 1, x}], {x, 1, 5}]
```

[image]

---

### Edited:

```
Plot[NIntegrate[eq, {ξ, 1, x}], {x, 0.1, 1}]
```

[image]

---

Anyway, you may want this:

```
expr[u_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[ξ^2 + ξ, {ξ, 1, u}];
FindRoot[expr[u] == 1, {u, 1}] // Quiet
```

Which will return you a numeric solution. (I change the expression to get a solution)

---

From the new information, I get this:

```
FindRoot[NIntegrate[eq, {ξ, 1, u}] == 6, {u, 0.2}]
```

> {u -> 0.334265}

---

Comment: @scrumpy.j I have updated the answer, now it works.